# Select com dados de tabelas associativas

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Estou criando um pequeno banco de dados para armazenar os livros que possuo em casa, mas me deparei com a seguinte situação: Eu tenho duas tabelas associativas, uma chamada  **autor_livro**, que permite que um mesmo livro tenha diversos autores e uma chamada **genero_livro**, que permite que um determinado livro faça parte de um ou mais genêros(dois, para ser exato). O meu problema está na hora de criar um **SELECT** que traga as informações dos livros(por exemplo: autores, qtd de páginas), mas que também traga quais genêros esse livro faz parte. Eu consegui criar a consulta, mas o meu código está repetindo diversas vezes os autores e os generos dos livros. O que estaria causando essa repetição?

Segue o meu código(estou utilizando o MYSQL):

```
SELECT group_concat(a.nome) as 'Autores', l.titulo as 'Título', l.pag as 'Páginas', group_concat(g.tipo), e.nome as 'Editora' 
FROM autor_livro al
INNER JOIN autor a ON a.id_autor = al.autor
INNER JOIN livro l ON l.id_livro = al.livro
INNER JOIN editora e ON e.id_editora = l.editora
INNER JOIN genero_livro gl ON gl.livro = al.livro
INNER JOIN genero g ON g.id_genero = gl.genero
GROUP BY al.livro;
```

Comment: Vejo que vc não comentou qual a saída final. Vc quer somente poder ver os dados no phpMyadmin (ou outro programa de mysql...)? É só para consulta pessoal? Se estiver usando php para concatenar os resultadps vc pode criar arrays associativos para agrupá-los. Se for esse o caso posso dar exemplos, mas se for somente por MYSQL acho que não poderia ajudar mto...

Comment: Perdão, amigo. Por agora eu ainda não implementei para nenhuma linguagem. Estou utilizando apenas o MYSQL mesmo.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat leai sobre group_concat pode ser uma solução para este caso

Comment: @Motta Amigo, era justamente isso que estava faltando. Quando adicionei o "distinct" no meu group_concat(), ele parou de exibir dados repetidos. Seria correto utilizar o distinct sempre que utilizar o group_concat? Agradeço a ajuda!

Comment: O group_contact dispensa o distinct , sua saída terá algo como :: a volta do q ñ foram manuel da silva/joaquim da silva